# Material chip color not working when I set it

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material 8.2.3 and when I try to set chip color chip is still greyed

```
<mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip color="accent" removable (removed)="removeFilter()">
        Filter view on {{dateFrom | date:'yyyy:MM:dd'}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

I have tried all colors (warn, primary etc..) but still color of the chip remains grey. Does anyone know why?

Comment: The color is only shown if the user has selected it.

Comment: Have you properly configured a theme (indigo/pink etc)? That's the only reason I can think of why the color isn't showing.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Apparently, the color is only applied to `mat-chip` once it's selected.

To mark the `mat-chip` as selected, you need to give it a `selected` attribute.

Here, give this a try:

```
<mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip selected color="accent" removable (removed)="removeFilter()">
        Filter view on {{dateFrom | date:'yyyy:MM:dd'}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

> Here's a [**Sample Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-chip-color?file=src/app/chips-overview-example.html) for your ref.

### UPDATE: Since Angular Material v15:

`mat-chip-list` has been replaced with `mat-chip-listbox`.

So if you're using Angular Material v15, the code would look like:

```
<mat-chip-listbox>
    <mat-chip selected color="accent" removable (removed)="removeFilter()">
        Filter view on {{dateFrom | date:'yyyy:MM:dd'}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-listbox>
```

### UPDATE: Since Angular Material v16:

To mark the `mat-chip` as selected, you will need to give it a <s>`selected`</s> `highlighted` attribute.

So if you're using Angular Material v16, the code would look like:

```
<mat-chip-listbox>
    <mat-chip highlighted color="accent" removable (removed)="removeFilter()">
        Filter view on {{dateFrom | date:'yyyy:MM:dd'}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-listbox>
```

> Here's a [**Sample Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-chip-color-phqzs4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-overview-example.html) for your ref.

Comment: Please consider elaborating on how your answer solves the problem.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thanks

Comment: this added a check mark in materials 16.

Answer (score 2):

**For Angular Material 16**

To solve this issue use the attribute `highlighted` instead of using `selected`.

Using `selected` added a check mark to the chip, where as `highlighted` will add the color you set without the checkmark.

```html
<mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip highlighted color="accent" removable (removed)="removeFilter()">
        Filter view on {{dateFrom | date:'yyyy:MM:dd'}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

If you are using `mat-chip-listbox` and you dont want the checkmark to show at all, you can add the `hideSingleSelectionIndicator` to the `mat-chip-listbox`

```html
<mat-chip-listbox hideSingleSelectionIndicator>
    ... your chips here
</mat-chip-listbox>
```

[Materials Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/api#directives)